# Use New Validations Module or Collection Handling module in mule 3.7.0 / 3.6.2

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I tried using new validations module

```
<validate:time time="12:08 PM" pattern="h:mm a" locale="US" />,
```

but mule is not able to recognize the same.
What dependencies should I include to make this work

Ref - 
https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/wiki/%5B3.5-Feb-2014%5D-New-Validations-Module
https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/wiki/%5B3.5%5D-Collection-Handling

Answer (score -1):

Especially for the validations module the `throwOnUnaccepted` field within filters does the trick, else composing filters like below

```
<message-filter throwOnUnaccepted="true">
   <mulexml:schema-validation-filter... />
</message-filter>
```

Comment: No I was specifically talking about the validation module. Like the example provided